# Event Extractor from text

Tags: machine-learning

I am trying to build an application which would extract event details like date,time,place from an image file.I would convert the image to text using Tesseract OCR.Now from text,what can I use to get the event details?I was planning to use machine learning but have no idea how to begin.

Answer (score -1):

Extracting date, time & place like stuff from raw text comes more under natural language processing. You can use any of the nlp frameworks like opennlp, stanford nlp.